# Winginx stopped working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, winginx

Tried to open Winginx and got an error that it stopped working (image). I'm using Windows 10

[Winginx stopped working Windows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CzDM.png)

Windows error reporting in event viewer shows this error (information level):

[Winginx event viewer error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILCr9.png)

I can't figure out how to fix this. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Not sure what part of `DirectoryNotFound` you're having difficulty understanding...

Comment: The part where it doesn't say which directory is not found. And it worked perfectly well a few days back and today it just doesn't work. I didn't change anything

Comment: I resolved the issue by a new installation of winginx